# Access Single-Pass RenderTexture

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, steam-vr

I'm trying to achieve a mirror effect where a second camera renders to a render texture, which is then passed into a shader using SetGlobalTexture.

Everything works fine outside of VR, but in Steam VR it seems like the render texture only stores the texture for one eye (left), even with single-pass stereo enabled in player settings.

How can I access the texture for the second eye? Or rather, how can I access the texture where both eyes have been drawn, one on each half of the screen?

What I'm doing at the moment:

```
void Awake()
{
    mirrorCameraRenderTexture = new RenderTexture(vrCam.pixelWidth, vrCam.pixelHeight, 24);
    mirrorCamera.targetTexture = mirrorCameraRenderTexture;

    Shader.SetGlobalTexture("_MirrorCameraRenderTexture", mirrorCameraRenderTexture);
}
```

Comment: By "Stores the texture for one eye" do you mean that it uses the same texture for both eyes, or is it Black / Blank in one eye?